# Choosing ADC with wide input voltage range (0-10V)

Tags: adc, component-selection

I faced with the task to measure several inputs (0-10V analog) with galvanic isolation.

Using plain Google search (like '[0-10V adc](http://www.google.com/search?q=0-10V%20adc&oq=0-10V%20adc&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)') I found several solutions like Linear Technology LTC1854/55/56 which has 8 inputs (single ended or 4 differential), -10...+10V input range (reference and supply voltage generated by the IC) which is very convenient. Galvanic isolation can be easily achieved by digital interface decoupling.

However this IC has SPI digital interface. I'd prefer I2C.

So I go to selector tools at several sellers and manufactures but no one has an option to choose wide input range. I can choose resolution, sampling rate, analog and digital power supply voltage... Anything! But I see no opportunity to filter ADCs with wide voltage inputs.

Can anyone suggest how can I search needed device? Maybe this parameter can be referred as "wide input range" or anything else? Maybe there are any selector tools allowing me to 
choose this option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, many manufacturers offer a parametric search page where you can access ALL the parameters and select which ones to use in the selection table.  For example, see, http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/10169#/d=sel|0|-1|7|88|165|4364|4746|186|3970|2846|4363|4307|164|4223|-3|4168  The Vref range max is selectable throught the "choose Parameters" button, and there are a handful that go up to 10V

Next,the "with galvanic isolation" part infers that there's much more to the design than finding a 10V ADC.  If you can't find what you're looking for in terms of ADC, consider a preamp with a gain of 0.5, if resolution concerns allow you to do this.

Comment: Thank you! This is really works. However: how did you reach this parametric search? If I choose `analog.com`->`Products`->`A/D converters`->`All A/D converters`->`Click to see all parametric search` - there is no 'voltage reference' parameter like it is in your link.

Comment: Clear! It was needed to press 'Choose parameters' button in the upper part of the selector.